# Candidature - problem with suffix- ship

Tags: suffixes

Can 'Candidature-Ship' be proper word . or it must be just Candidature !
Like , I would like to apply my candidature -ship for the post Retail Manager . 
Is the sentence is Valid ?

Comment: Why not *candidatureshipness*?

Comment: The word is "candidateship" (OED), but means exactly the same thing as "candidature", which is more commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

Don’t use either in the way you propose.

For clarification, the state or condition of being a candidate is “candidature” or “candidacy”.

But you’re not applying to be a candidate for the job, you’re applying to be hired for the job. So I think you’d want to say:

> I would like to apply for the Retail Manager position.

Answer (score 0):

The term is  ***[candidateship](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Candidateship)*** but it is actually very rare;

> Candidacy

(Webster's Revised Unabridged Dictionary, published 1913 by G. & C. Merriam Co.)

The more commonly used term is ***candidacy*** as shown   in [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=candidateship%2C%20candidacy%2C%20candidature%20&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccandidateship%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccandidacy%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccandidature%3B%2Cc0).

In the context you are suggesting you are *applying for job/position* and you might say, for instance:

> “I hope my candidacy/application receives favourable consideration"